# Combination: Teacher puts together a test worth 100 points.

Tags: combinations

A Teacher puts together a test worth 100 points. There are 10 questions. Each question must award atleast a score of 5 points. Each score is a whole number. How many ways are there to arrange the 100 points?

Comment: What are the allowable scores for a question?  Can a question be worth $5+\sqrt 2$ points? How about $ 7? 43?$  Does order matter?  Is the first five being worth $15$ and the last five being worth $5$ different from starting with five questions worth $5$?  Please think about your question and supply enough information to answer it.

Comment: The only constraint is that each individual score cannot be lower than 5. Everything else goes. So 50 of those points have effectively already been set.

Comment: Then there are continuum many ways to arrange the points. -1

Comment: What if the only allowed points are whole numbers.

Comment: changed description to reflect constraints properly.

Comment: Hint: stars and bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you assign the mandatory $5$ points to each question, you have $50$ left to distribute.  Assuming the order matters, you are looking for [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $50$ into $10$ parts which can be computed by the usual [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach.  This gives ${59 \choose 9}=12\ 565\ 671\ 261$ compositions